# Is there a way to find the expiry date of a Google OAuth refresh token?

Tags: google-oauth

I know the access_tokens have "expires_in": nAmountofSeconds in the response body. Is there a way to find something similar for the refresh token from Google?   I know for production apps / projects, this should be indefinite.  But, for apps / projects in testing status, this is 7 days.  I just want to know whether the refresh token I receive is indefinite or 7 days without having to wait 7 days to see whether the refresh token no longer works.

Much thanks,

Comment: If google's oauth API supports the 'introspection' feature you might be able to obtain that information.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way of knowing when the refresh token will expire.   You could just log when it was created and then you will know the expiration date from that.

If you want a bit of fun trivia.  The refresh token doesn't exactly expire.  The users authorization grant to your app is revoked via the users google account, this in effect will expire all refresh tokens automatically.

So google must just track when authorization was granted and then revokes it. This is why you need to request authorization again to get a new token, the token didn't expire exactly.

TBH it doesn't matter your code should be designed to handle bad refresh tokens and simply request authorization again when you get the invalid grant error.

Comment: Much thanks for the response. I was hoping to not wait 7 days to find out whether I have the indefinite refresh_token.  Logging the time stamp is not going to solve that.

Comment: As an aside, do you know if the refresh_token must be used from the same uri as the redirection_uri used in the initial OAuth authorization?  So, as a test, I've been playing around with Google's Oauth Playground.  I eventually get an access token, and if I use the access token to make a simple API GET request to Google from anywhere such as postman.com or script.google.com (Apps Script), it works fine.  However, if I try to use the refresh token to get a new access_token, I get the generic "invalid_grant" error. The POST options are setup correctly. THoughts? I might make this another post.

Comment: TBH i wouldnt bother with the time stamp either the seven days isnt exactly perfect.

Comment: Open a new question with your second comment with some code I would love to test it.  In theory you should be able to use the refresh token from anywhere.   Refreshing the access token doesnt require a redirect uri so i cant see why it would be an issue.

Comment: Will do. It will have to wait till the morning, though.  Much thanks.